# Enemy's despawn after being rendered (Java Game)

Tags: java

I am spawning 60 enemy's over the course of 60 seconds, however when 1 enemy is rendered, the previous enemy is somehow removed and replaced with the next enemy. I can't work out why this is happening, the render method is being called every second in my game loop.

This is the Enemy class where i am trying to make it happen, Any help would be greatly appreciated

public class ZombieSwarm extends GameObject{

```
Rectangle[] zombies = new Rectangle[60];

Timer timer = new Timer();

int spawnedZombies = 0;
int zombieX, zombieY;

public ZombieSwarm(float x, float y, ID id, SpriteSheet ss) {
    super(x, y, id, ss);

    Delay();
}

public void Delay(){
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 1000);

}

TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
{
    public void run()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int result = rand.nextInt(6);

        if(result == 0){
            zombieX = 1000;
            zombieY = 200;
        }

        if(result == 1){
            zombieX = 100;
            zombieY = 200;
        }

        if(result == 2){
            zombieX = 100;
            zombieY = 600;
        }

        if(result == 3){
            zombieX = 1000;
            zombieY = 600;
        }

        if(result == 4){
            zombieX = 100;
            zombieY = 900;
        }

        if(result == 5){
            zombieX = 1000;
            zombieY = 900;
        }

        zombies[spawnedZombies] = new Rectangle((int)zombieX, (int)zombieY, 32, 48);
        spawnedZombies++;

        if(spawnedZombies == zombies.length){
            task.cancel();
        }

    }
};

public void tick() {

}

public void render(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillRect((int)zombieX, (int)zombieY, 32, 48);

}

public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle((int)zombieX, (int)zombieY, 32, 48);
}
```

}

Comment: Perhaps you are rendering a single zombie in render function, you need to loop through your zombies and render them all?

Comment: You've solved it all lol, thank you!